# JQuery find closest with more than N children

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Html example:

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="findMe">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="findMe">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="findMe">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="notMe">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Desired result: `div.findMe` from each "html .test tree", **without using**: '.findMe', '[class]' & etc

---

Is it possible to find the closest **parent** that contains **more than 1 children**?

- Any nesting depth
- Choosing how many children there should be, or how many more

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the uniqueness (hook for the selector) is the number of children

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `$('.test').closestHasChild(3).first();` before `.first()`: `[.findMe, .notMe]`

Comment: Your requirements was 'has more than 1 child', not 'has exactly 3 children'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the first parent who has enough children. Somehow:

```js
const findMe = childsCount => $($('.test').find(`*>*:nth-child(${childsCount})`).parent().get(0));

// The first father in .test who has 3 children
findMe(3).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="findMe">
                <div>1.1</div>
                <div>1.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="findMe">
                    <div>2.1</div>
                    <div>2.2</div>
                    <div>2.3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="notMe">
                    <div>3.1</div>
                    <div>3.2</div>
                    <div>3.3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```